# how to factor out 3 custome uiView in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have the following ui

[image]

I want to refactor out the custom view which repeats 3 times.

Meaning that when I change the colour of the custom view, all 3 instances will be changed accordingly to have the same colour.In android I would add it by mentioning the custom view xml into the bigger layout xml

How can it be done in iOS?
How can I inject the different (images and text) - programmatically only?

Comment: are all the three views of same subclass ?IF yes, you can implement a simple uiview subclass and change its attributes there

Comment: but how do i interleave it with the big layout afterwards?

Comment: sorry i didnt get u. what do you mean by interleave with big layout ?

Comment: after you create uiview subclass how do you put it in the storyboard ui?

Comment: Design the storybaord as you like. Now add UIVIew file to your project and name it as some xView, and in the storybaord, select the uiview and in the file owner class, enter the uiview name. that's it

Comment: I think you want to look in to IBDesignable and IBInspectable. These things let you design your own Interface Builder views that render in Interface Builder. Here is a good starting point.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, create a subclass of `UIView` similar to this:

```
//.h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImageHolderView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
@end

//.m file
#import "ImageHolderView.h"

@implementation ImageHolderView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews{

    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

}

@end
```

You name the file owner of each individual `UIView` as the name of the subclass `UIVIew`.

[image]

Here you set the background color same for all the `UIView` you subclassed for.

And to set the individual image in the `UIView`, you do this in your `UIViewController`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ImageHolderView.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ImageHolderView *imgHOlder1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet ImageHolderView *imgHOlder2;
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet ImageHolderView *imgHOlder3;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    _imgHOlder1.imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"];
    _imgHOlder2.imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"code.png"];
    _imgHOlder3.imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"];
}
```

**Note**: The common attributes like background color, border color etc can be set in the `UIView` subclass, remaining properties which you want to be different for each `UIView` should be declared as properties in your subclassed `UIView` .h file, and set them in your `UIViewController`.

Comment: thanks, i will try to translate to swift